# Laravel Excel beforeExport event to load excel from aws s3 bucket not working

Tags: php, laravel, amazon-s3, laravel-excel

I am using matwebsite Laravel excel to do some updates in existing excel and export. I am using **beforeExport** method to do some updates in the excel. when i provide my local server path it works great but if i use amazon s3 bucket path it is not working. here in below $awsPath not working. if I use my local server file then it works

```
public static function beforeExport(beforeExport $event)
{
  $event->writer->reopen(new LocalTemporaryFile($awsPath),Excel::XLSX)
}
```

it returns below error

exception: "PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Reader\Exception"
file: "vendor\phpoffice\phpspreadsheet\src\PhpSpreadsheet\Shared\File.php"
line: 149
message: "File "" does not exist."

Comment: How do you define $awsPath? there is no definition of that in your example

Comment: @mrhn that my aws s3 bucket link. when i open that link it works good. i have not shared because it is against stackoverflow policy.

Comment: @mrhn any suggestions ?